# Import excel file to Table View JAVAFX Excel Streaming Reader

Tags: javafx, apache-poi, xlsx, streamreader, tablecolumn

i want to import xlsx file to a tableView, for that i'm using JAVAFX and for reading the file i'm using this [library](https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader)

i cant import the file because of only two variables nb3Col and amountCol that returns this error

the parameter in PropertyValueFactory is the same in the xml file

for the other variables nb1,nb2,account, idClient ... it works like a charm

**ERROR**

```
    Error:(100, 34) java: incompatible types: javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory<sample.Data,java.lang.String> cannot be converted to javafx.util.Callback<javafx.scene.control.TableColumn<sample.Data,java.lang.String>,javafx.scene.control.TableCell<sample.Data,java.lang.String>>
```

her is my Code

Main Class

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Excel Filter BNA");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1000, 1000));
        //primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        launch(args);

    }
}
```

Data Class

```
package sample;

import javafx.beans.InvalidationListener;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;

public class Data {


    private StringProperty nb1;
    private StringProperty account;
    private StringProperty nb2;
    private StringProperty nb3;
    private StringProperty idClient;
    private StringProperty amount;
    private StringProperty name;
    private StringProperty typeAccount;

    public Data(String nb1, String account, String nb2, String nb3, String idClient, String amount, String name, String typeAccount) {
        this.nb1 = new SimpleStringProperty(nb1);
        this.account = new SimpleStringProperty(account);
        this.nb2 = new SimpleStringProperty(nb2);
        this.nb3 = new SimpleStringProperty(nb3);
        this.idClient = new SimpleStringProperty(idClient);
        this.amount = new SimpleStringProperty(amount);
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.typeAccount = new SimpleStringProperty(typeAccount);
    }

    public void setNb1(String value) { nb1Property().set(value); }
    public String getNb1() { return nb1Property().get(); }
    public StringProperty nb1Property() {
        if (nb1 == null) nb1 = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "firstName");
        return nb1;
    }

    public void setAccount(String value) { accountProperty().set(value); }
    public String getAccount() { return accountProperty().get(); }
    public StringProperty accountProperty() {
        if (account == null)  account= new SimpleStringProperty(this,"account","");
        return account;
    }



    public void setNb2(String value) { this.nb2.set(value); }
    public String getNb2() {return nb2.get(); }
    public StringProperty nb2Property() {
        if (nb2 == null)  nb2= new SimpleStringProperty(this,"nb2","");
        return nb2;
    }


    public void setNb3(String nb3) { this.nb3.set(nb3);}
    public String getNb3() { return nb3.get();}
    public StringProperty nb3Property() {
        if(nb3 == null) nb3 = new SimpleStringProperty(this,"nb3","");
        return nb3;
    }


    public void setIdClient(String idClient) { this.idClient.set(idClient);    }
    public String getIdClient() { return idClient.get(); }
    public StringProperty idClientProperty() {
        if(idClient==null) idClient= new SimpleStringProperty(this,"idClient","");
        return idClient;
    }


    public void setAmount(String amount) {        this.amount.set(amount);    }
    public String getAmount() {        return amount.get();    }
    public StringProperty amountProperty() {
        if(amount==null) amount= new SimpleStringProperty(this,"amount","");
        return amount;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {        this.name.set(name);    }
    public String getName() {        return name.get();    }
    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        if(name==null) name = new SimpleStringProperty(this,"name","");
        return name;
    }

    public void setTypeAccount(String typeAccount) { this.typeAccount.set(typeAccount); }
    public String getTypeAccount() { return typeAccount.get();}
    public StringProperty typeAccountProperty() {
        if(typeAccount==null) typeAccount= new SimpleStringProperty(this,"typeAccount","");
        return typeAccount;
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Data{" +
                "nb1=" + nb1 +
                ", account=" + account +
                ", nb2=" + nb2 +
                ", nb3=" + nb3 +
                ", idClient=" + idClient +
                ", amount=" + amount +
                ", name=" + name +
                ", typeAccount=" + typeAccount +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Controller Class**

```
package sample;

import com.monitorjbl.xlsx.StreamingReader;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {


    ObservableList<Data> observableDataList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    @FXML
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML
    private URL location;

    //-------------TABLE COLUMN------------
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Data, String> nb1Col; // fx:id="firstNameCol"

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Data, String> accountCol; // fx:id="lastNameCol"

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Data, String> nb2Col; // fx:id="netIDCol"

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Data, Number> nb3Col; // fx:id="ageCol"

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Data, String> idClientCol; // fx:id="gpaCol"

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Data,String> amountCol ;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Data, String> nameCol;  // fx:id="uinCol"

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Data, String> typeAccountCol; // fx:id="genderCol"

    //-----------------TEXT FIELD---------
    @FXML
    private TextField nameField; // fx:id="nameField"

    @FXML
    private TextField clientIDField; // fx:id="clientIDField"

    @FXML
    private TextField impIDField; // fx:id="impIDField"

    //----------Combo Box---------------

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> accountBox = new ComboBox<>();  // fx:id="accountBox"

    ObservableList<String> accountBoxData = FXCollections.observableArrayList("ANSEG", "Credit auto confort", "credit immobilier", "CNAC", "ANGEM");


    //-----------------Observable Data List-------------
    @FXML
    private TableView<Data> dataTableView;
    //--------------- BUTTON--------------
    @FXML
    private Button clearBtn; // fx:id="clearBtn"

    @FXML
    private Button filterBtn;  // fx:id="filterBtn"
    //-----------------MENU BAR-------------
    @FXML
    private MenuBar fileMenu;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        accountBox.setItems(accountBoxData);

        nb1Col.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Data, String>("nb1"));
        accountCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Data, String>("account"));
        nb2Col.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Data, String>("nb2"));
        nb3Col.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Data, String>("nb3"));
        idClientCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Data, String>("idClient"));
        amountCol.setCellFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Data,String>("amount"));
        accountCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Data, String>("account"));
        nameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Data, String>("name"));
        typeAccountCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Data, String>("typeAccount"));

    }
    public void load(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        fileChooser.setTitle("Open file");
        File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(accountBox.getScene().getWindow());
        System.out.println(file.getPath());
        InputStream fileIn ;
        Workbook workbook ;



            fileIn = new FileInputStream(file.getPath());
            workbook = StreamingReader.builder().rowCacheSize(100).bufferSize(4096).open(fileIn);
            Sheet sheet= workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            String a0=null,a= null,a1= null,a2= null,a3= null,a4= null,a5= null,a6= null,a7= null;
            System.out.println(sheet.getSheetName());
            int i=0;
            for (Row row : sheet ) {
                    i++;
                    if(i != 1) {


                        try {
                            Data data = new Data(a0=row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue(),
                                    a =row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue(),
                                    a1 =row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue(),
                                    a2 =row.getCell(3).getStringCellValue(),
                                    a3 =row.getCell(4).getStringCellValue(),
                                    a4 =row.getCell(5).getStringCellValue(),
                                    a5 =row.getCell(6).getStringCellValue(),
                                    a6 =row.getCell(7).getStringCellValue()
                                    );
                           // Data data = new Data("katia", "asmaa", "152", "588", "5", "as", "88", "78");
                            fillTable(observableDataList,data);
                            System.out.print(a0+"\t"+a+"\t"+"\t"+a1+"\t"+a2+"\t"+a3+"\t"+a4+"\t"+a5+"\t"+a5+"\t"+a6);
                        }catch (NullPointerException nullp){
                            //System.out.print(a0+"\t"+a+"\t"+"\t"+a1+"\t"+a2+"\t"+a3+"\t"+a4+"\t"+a5+"\t"+a5+"\t"+a6);
                            System.out.println("null");
                        }





                    }
                }
    }



    private void fillTable(ObservableList<Data> observableDataList,Data data) {

        observableDataList.add(data);
        dataTableView.setItems(observableDataList);

    }
}
```

**XML FILE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SeparatorMenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

<SplitPane dividerPositions="0.7506265664160401" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
    <items>
        <AnchorPane>
            <children>
                <HBox minWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="1000.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                    <children>
                        <MenuBar fx:id="fileMenu" prefWidth="1000.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
                            <menus>
                                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
                                    <items>
                                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#load" text="importer un fichier excel" />
                                        <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
                              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Exporter " />
                              <SeparatorMenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" />
                                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Fermer" />
                                    </items>
                                </Menu>
                            </menus>
                        </MenuBar>
                    </children>
                </HBox>
                <TableView fx:id="dataTableView" layoutX="1.0" layoutY="30.0" prefHeight="566.0" prefWidth="1000.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="1.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="30.0">
                    <columns>
                        <TableColumn fx:id="nb1Col" prefWidth="124.0" text="NB " />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="accountCol" prefWidth="131.0" text="Compte" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="nb2Col" prefWidth="121.0" text="NB" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="nb3Col" prefWidth="149.0"  text="NB"/>
                        <TableColumn fx:id="idClientCol" prefWidth="170.0" text="IDENT" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="amountCol" prefWidth="76.0" text="Montant" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="nameCol" prefWidth="70.0" text="Nom et prénom" />
                        <TableColumn fx:id="genderCol" prefWidth="155.0" text="Gender" />
                  <TableColumn fx:id="typeAccountCol" prefWidth="75.0" text="Type Compte" />
                    </columns>
                </TableView>
            </children></AnchorPane>
        <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="1000.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="1000.0">
            <children>
                <HBox />
                <TextField fx:id="nameField" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" promptText="Nom et Prénom..." />
                <TextField fx:id="clientIDField" layoutX="201.0" layoutY="14.0" promptText="ID Client..." />
                <TextField fx:id="impIDField" layoutX="201.0" layoutY="54.0" promptText="ID IMP..." />
                <ComboBox fx:id="accountBox" layoutX="389.0" layoutY="14.0" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="Compte" />
                <Button fx:id="clearBtn" layoutX="624.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Supprimer " />
            <Button fx:id="filterBtn" layoutX="624.0" layoutY="54.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="75.0" text="Filtrer" />
            </children></AnchorPane>
    </items>
</SplitPane>
```

Comment: You forgot the `Value` part of `setCellValueFactory`. `cellFactory`s are used to create cells and this is nothing `PropertyValueFactory` can be used for.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56903053/how-to-read-data-from-excel-in-javafx-application/56904559#56904559

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56462624/read-excel-and-show-it-on-tableview-populate-tableview-using-2d-array-or-list-o/56528141#56528141